# Microsoft Teams Webhook Generating 400 for Adaptive Card

Tags: json, http-post, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, http-status-code-400

I have a functioning webhook to a Teams channel to which I can successfully post messages.  I am now trying to post an adaptive card to the webhook.  Using Postman and performing a Post to https://outlook.office.com/webhook/xyz, with `Content-Type` set to `application/json` in the header and the following adaptive card set in the body.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "speak": "Nothing to say.",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Hello Teams' user"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this I receive a HTTP 400 Bad Request and *Summary or Text is required* message. Does anyone know if Teams webhooks support *Adaptive Cards* yet or if this is an unsupported task currently?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer below is now deprecated. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68203359/109941) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70109571/109941).

<strike>Webhooks do not yet support Adaptive Cards! We plan to add support for Adaptive Cards shortly after we release them for bots.</strike>

Answer (score 21):

I'm using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to send an Adaptive Card to a Teams Connector and I was getting this same error. In my case, I was able to resolve the issue by wrapping the card as an "attachment" to the message protocol shown in this link (syntax copied here for reference).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook

```json
{
   "type":"message",
   "attachments":[
      {
         "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
         "contentUrl":null,
         "content":{
            "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "type":"AdaptiveCard",
            "version":"1.4",
            "body":[
                {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "For Samples and Templates, see [https://adaptivecards.io/samples](https://adaptivecards.io/samples)"
                }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

By sending the above JSON as the request body (`data` argument for axios), I successfully got the Adaptive Card to show up in my Teams Channel.

As you can see, the value of `"content"` is the Adaptive Card structure. The Adaptive Card follows the documented syntax, found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/getting-started

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/400502/adaptive-cards-with-incoming-webhooks-in-microsoft.html

But ultimately, I found it easier to work with this "Designer" https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer/
which provides a WYSIWYG interface.

I am sending the request to a Connector that I created in Teams by following the instructions found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook#create-incoming-webhook-1

And now it responds with 200 OK and shows up in the Channel!

Comment: If you're still having trouble, I recommend logging your request so that you can double-check for a silly mistake like nesting a duplicate request body or accidentally Stringifying your JSON twice. I mean who would make such a silly mistake though? *sweats nervously*

Comment: This seems to be the official supported method. See additional documentation here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook

Comment: Note, this also works for "MessageCard" types (the connector card type here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#example-of-a-connector-card-for-microsoft-365-groups). Just add the example there as an object in the "attachments" list.

Answer (score 10):

For simple use cases POST this to the webhook url:

```
{
  "title": "Action News",
  "text": "not **much** happend (markdown)"
}
```

For advanced use cases try using MessageCard: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using

Example:

```
{
"@type": "MessageCard",
"@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
"themeColor": "0076D7",
"summary": "Larry Bryant created a new task",
"sections": [{
    "activityTitle": "![TestImage](https://47a92947.ngrok.io/Content/Images/default.png)Larry Bryant created a new task",
    "activitySubtitle": "On Project Tango",
    "activityImage": "https://teamsnodesample.azurewebsites.net/static/img/image5.png",
    "facts": [{
        "name": "Assigned to",
        "value": "Unassigned"
    }, {
        "name": "Due date",
        "value": "Mon May 01 2017 17:07:18 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
    }, {
        "name": "Status",
        "value": "Not started"
    }],
    "markdown": true
}],
"potentialAction": [{
    "@type": "ActionCard",
    "name": "Add a comment",
    "inputs": [{
        "@type": "TextInput",
        "id": "comment",
        "isMultiline": false,
        "title": "Add a comment here for this task"
    }],
    "actions": [{
        "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "Add comment",
        "target": "http://..."
    }]
}, {
    "@type": "ActionCard",
    "name": "Set due date",
    "inputs": [{
        "@type": "DateInput",
        "id": "dueDate",
        "title": "Enter a due date for this task"
    }],
    "actions": [{
        "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "Save",
        "target": "http://..."
    }]
}, {
    "@type": "ActionCard",
    "name": "Change status",
    "inputs": [{
        "@type": "MultichoiceInput",
        "id": "list",
        "title": "Select a status",
        "isMultiSelect": "false",
        "choices": [{
            "display": "In Progress",
            "value": "1"
        }, {
            "display": "Active",
            "value": "2"
        }, {
            "display": "Closed",
            "value": "3"
        }]
    }],
    "actions": [{
        "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "Save",
        "target": "http://..."
    }]
}]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can actually send your adaptive card body inside the body array of this structure:

```
{
"type": "message",
"attachments": [
    {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "contentUrl": null,
        "content": {
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.4",
            "body": [
                
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

Reference: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/400502/adaptive-cards-with-incoming-webhooks-in-microsoft.html)

Answer (score 2):

Recently I was facing the same issue and was looking for a solution. The good part is MS Teams support adaptive cards now
[youtube video to explain how it can be implemented](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5pbJI43Zvg)

[Github link to track the progress on the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/3740)

I managed to send messages to the Teams channel without any failure.