# Converting Adaptive Cards to MessageCards

Tags: adaptive-cards

Is there any example code or guidance for converting Adaptive Cards to MessageCards?

The Adaptive Card schema is specified [here](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/) but I can't find a similar specification for MessageCards.

Comment: Is this the specification you're looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference

Comment: What makes you think MS Teams doesn't support Adaptive Cards? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card

Comment: Because of problems like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753072/microsoft-teams-webhook-generating-400-for-adaptive-card/50753413

Comment: Okay I had a feeling you just meant one specific part of MS Teams. So you're talking about webhooks.

Comment: Your question is about MessageCards. Has that question been answered? I cannot see who upvoted my comment.

Comment: You've provided the MessageCards spec, thanks for that - the upvote was me. But I'm still interested to know if anyone has done work on this before I start.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any example code or guidance for converting Adaptive Cards to MessageCards?

No there is not, but depending on the specifics of your cards you should be able to work it out by examining the capabilities of both.

This document should help you use MessageCards, which are the legacy version of actionable messages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference

There's also a handy guide here: https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/microsoft-message-cards-the-ultimate-guide/